# With Combine, how can you flatMap with nil-coalescing

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, combine

I have a publisher which emits an optional output type. I need to `flatMap` to a new publisher if the output isn't `nil`, or fallback to an empty publisher if it is `nil`.

For example, something like:

```swift
[1, nil, 5].publisher // Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
    .flatMap {
        $0?.someNewPublisher ?? Empty(completeImmediately: false)
    }
```

```swift
[1, nil, 5].publisher
    .map {
        $0?.someNewPublisher
    }
    .replaceNil(with: Empty(completeImmediately: false)) // Generic parameter 'Failure' could not be inferred
    .flatMap { $0 }
```

I'm wondering if maybe I'm trying to solve this in the wrong way. Just to be clear, filtering `nil` before mapping would not solve my issue, as that would not replace a current publisher with an empty publisher (I would continue to receive elements which I should no longer be receiving).

Comment: Adding `eraseToAnyPublisher` to your first code snippet works.

Comment: I already tried that and it doesn't work. Can you post your answer showing where exactly you mean for that to be used? Your meaning is a bit ambiguous as is.

Comment: Charles Maria's answer is way better actually. Oh the power of composing monads :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an `Optional.Publisher` type. If you call `.publisher` on an optional value you’ll get a publisher that either produces the wrapped type or completes immediately.

`optionalValue.publisher.flatMap(\.someNewPublisher)`

Edit:

Since this functionality is gatekept to iOS14+, here is an extension that creates the same functionality but as a function so that it doesn't collide with the naming of the `publisher` `var`.

Note that I'm not setting `completeImmediately` to  `false`, it’s automatically set to `true`, and setting it to `false` means the publisher will never complete.

```
extension Optional {
    func publisher() -> AnyPublisher<Wrapped, Never> {
        switch self {
        case let .some(wrapped):
            return Just(wrapped).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        case .none:
            return Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, but unfortunately `.publisher` is only in iOS 14+. I tried achieving the same solution via a combination of `Just` with `compactMap`, but it ended up being much more unreadable.

Comment: This is a late reply, but while `someOptional.publisher` is only in iOS14, you can manually create an `Optional.Publisher` with its `init(_:)` method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/publisher-swift.struct/init(_:) since it's available in iOS13.

Answer (score 2):

Your original approach will work, it just looks like you need to specify the types because the compiler is having trouble with they type inference.

Specifying the return type in the flat map does the trick

Note in combine each publisher has it's own type and each time you use an operator it returns a different (chained) type, so use the type eraser .eraseToAnyPublisher() liberally.

[image]